# Error when running a cron job for Moodle 4.1+

Tags: cron, moodle

Moodle works normally, I create courses, install plugins and etc.
However, the only problem is related to the execution of cron.php (admin/cli/cron.php)
It doesn't matter the user or permission.
I have already enabled, in the server settings, that cron.php can be executed in the browser.
Nothing, yet, has worked.

Error inline command:

```
!!! <p>Error: Database connection failed</p>
<p>It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.</p>
<p>The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php</p> !!!
```

Error in the browser:

```
Command line scripts can not be executed from the web interface
```

I thank.

It doesn't matter the user or permission.
I have already enabled, in the server settings, that cron.php can be executed in the browser.
Nothing, yet, has worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 versions of cron

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Cron

The web version is at `yourmoodlesite.com/admin/cron.php` which you can run from the browser, but its not recommended

The cli version is at `admin/cli/cron.php` which can be run from the command line and is used for the server cron

```
php admin/cli/cron.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the user matter greatly^^

The thing is that your cron job should be setted up on your machine first of all since it's where the used credentials'll be from.

Your cron job needs to be done from your apache user (if no apache then nginx), which'll be www-data

According you're on a debian based server you can do

```
sudo -i #be root
crontab -u www-data -e #edit the crontab of www-data user
* * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path-to-your-moodle/admin/cli/cron.php 
#enter code here#change the * for desired values
```